# functools has no attribute lru_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I'm using Python 3.7 on my Windows

This error occurs while running every code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
    import signal
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\signal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functools import wraps as _wraps
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\tweepy\keyword.py", line 1, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 297, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache(_MAXCACHE)
AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What does the following script show you: `import functools; print(functools)`

Comment: @Jeronimo <module 'functools' from 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\functools.py'>

Answer (score 6):

It looks like someone published a `functools` package on pypi, so if you had run:

```py
# don't run this!
pip install functools
```

You may have accidentally installed that package. If you encounter this error, I would:

```py
pip uninstall functools
```

To make sure that the functools you are using are the base package functools.

(I ended up here because I attempted to use `functools.cache`, which seems to only be present in Python 3.8, not earlier.)

Comment: It is actually added only in 3.9

Comment: Thanks! I had the issue with `functools.cache` and using python 3.7 so it's explained.